# Filter php mysqli sql query from html input text box

Tags: php, mysqli, drop-down-menu, filter

I am trying to filter the value displayed in a select box, based on another value in input textbox in html modal form. I am getting the following error"Notice: Undefined index: gender in C:\xampp\htdocs\series\Register\indexentries1.php on line 3". If i test it and use a value like "Male" instead of "'".$_POST["gender"]."' then it does filter and display correctly in select box.

```
  <?php
include("connection.php");
$query = "SELECT * FROM tblcategories WHERE gender = '".$_POST["gender"]."'";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
$output = '';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
 $output .= '<option value="'.$row["category_id"].'">'.$row["category_name"].'</option>';
}" error.
?>
```

In the html side i have 
`<input type="text" name="gender" placeholder="Gender" id="gender"/>` that has a value ie "Male" already.
  select box:

```
<label>Select Category</label>
 <select name="category_id" id="category_id" class="form-control" >
 <option value="">Select Category</option>
  <?php echo $output; ?>
 </select>
```

How can i filter this "$output value" based on "gender value" in input text box. Please assist this novice PHP programmer. thx

I also use

```
 $(document).on("loaded.rs.jquery.bootgrid", function()
 {
  usersTable.find(".update").on("click", function(event)
  {
   var id = $(this).data("row-id");
    $.ajax({
    url:"fetch_single_entries.php",
    method:"POST",
    data:{id:id},
    dataType:"json",
    success:function(data)
    {
     $('#usersModal').modal('show');
     $('#category_id').val(data.category_id);
     $('#category_name').val(data.category_name);
     $('#idno').val(data.idno);
     $('#surname').val(data.surname);
     $('#firstname').val(data.firstname);
     $('#age').val(data.age);
     $('#gender').val(data.gender);

     $('.modal-title').text("Edit Entries");
     $('#id').val(id);
     $('#action').val("Edit");
     $('#operation').val("Edit");
    }
   });
  });
 });
```

And this fetch form to populate the modal

```
<?php
//fetch_single.php
include("connection.php");
if(isset($_POST["id"]))
{
 //$output = array();
 $query = "SELECT * FROM tblentries WHERE id = '".$_POST["id"]."'";
 $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 {
  $output["category_id"] = $row["category_id"];
    $output["category_name"] = $row["category_name"];
     $output["idno"] = $row["idno"];
   $output["surname"] = $row["surname"];
   $output["firstname"] = $row["firstname"];
  $output["age"] = $row["age"];
  $output["gender"] = $row["gender"];


 }
 echo json_encode($output);
}

?>
```

I removed some of the fields above

Comment: The error suggests that the input value isn't being sent to the server.  Is it part of a form?  How are you sending it?

Comment: before using a variable, you might want to check that it exists.. 
`if ((isset($_POST["gender"])) && (!empty($_POST["gender"]))){ use VAR;} else {echo 'ERROR: No gender set';}

Comment: The form input textbox is populated with the gender value on opening. It suppose to filter the category select box then or i hope. PHP code above is on top of the   html       I get this error - Duane with your check    "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\series\Register\indexentries1.php on line 3"

Comment: I added more code i use to populate html form and gender input text box above. Hope it helps. Thx

Comment: David i think you are correct. I figured that the $gender only gets populated in the modal form when it opens, based on the row selected in the table, while the selectbox has already populated from the sql query. Somehow and need this $gender to be populated before the selectbox is populated.